# How to update all child IDs using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function called `resetIndex`. It works fine but I want to reset all child IDs. How can I do this? Is there any method like `firstChild` and `lastChild`?

I'm new with JavaScript. Can anyone help?

I have following function:

```js
function resetIndex(delId) {
  for (var i = delId + 1; i < count; i++) {
    var currentElement = document.getElementById(i);
    currentElement.id = i - 1;
    var update = currentElement.childNodes;
    update.setAttribute('id', 'deleteLink(' + currentElement.id + ')');
  }
  count--;
}
```

Comment: you have to iterate again over `update` and set recursively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`node.children[0]`

to get the first one, and

`node.children[node.children.length - 1]`

to get the last one.

Make sure to check if they exist, first.

To do something to all child-nodes, you can use a for-loop, like

```
for(let a = 0; a < node.children.length; a++) {
  node.children[a].id = "my-new-id";
}
```

Comment: You asked for first/last-child. I updated the answer to manipulate all child-elements.